# Bitcoin-qt exits silently after syncing blocks until before 24 hours

Tags: synchronization, full-node

I shutdown bitcoin-qt (version: 23.0) around two weeks back. Now when I relaunch it, it syncs blocks until 24 hours and then silently exits. debug.log file contains the following as last line -

2022-09-26T13:28:01Z Leaving InitialBlockDownload (latching to false)

I removed all the wallets to see if that is causing any issue, but that was in vain. Any help will be appreciated.

Best.

Comment: Hi, is there anything uncommon in how you set up your node? Are you running your node with some uncommon startup options or config? Is it running in pruning mode? It would help if you could tell us a bit more.

Comment: Nothing specific. I have been running nodes for more than a year now, never faced this issue. Only thing uncommon would be Tor onion, though I don't think that is uncommon.

Comment: I tried to run bitcoind as well, but that also exited after syncing until 24 hours.

Comment: Here is the content of bicoin.conf

daemon=1
txindex=1
server=1
listen=1

proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
bind=127.0.0.1

onlynet=onion

walletbroadcast=0

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it out in kind of hacky way. I watched the behavior of Bitcoin-qt during multiple sync attempts I did. The moment it used to come at 24 hrs mark, it used to get stuck there for few minutes. My guess was, it may be in some code path which will cause it to exit after some time. So I decided to perform some operation just as a hunch. And it helped.

Here is what I did - I launched the bitcoin-qt and it started to sync. When it reached 24 hours mark, I waited for a minute or so and then I created a blank wallet using the UI. It did the magic, this time sync moved beyond 24 hours and synced the whole way through. Bitcoin node is now up again and running successfully.